# How to overwrite the last line of text file

Tags: c#-4.0, filestream

```
FileStream files = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);                       
StreamWriter cmdswriter = new StreamWriter(files);
cmdswriter.Write("last line content");
```

Comment: Is the file too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is not too large:

```
string path = "text.txt";
var fileContent = File.ReadLines(path).ToList();

fileContent[fileContent.Count - 1] = "last line content";
File.WriteAllLines(path, fileContent);
```

Comment: @Harsh... Glad that helped. You can follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to accept an answer

Answer (score 3):

Nether OS nor Filesystem haven't got a clue about what is the `line`. You have to open a file, seek at the end and read it backwards until you get the `end-of-line` character. Everything after this position is the last line.

```
FileStream files = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter cmdswriter = new StreamWriter(files);
cmdswriter.BaseStream.Seek("line content to overwrite".Length * -1, SeekOrigin.End);
cmdswriter.Write("last line content");
cmdswriter.Flush();
cmdswriter.Close();
```